# How to remove strock border

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Could you please check out this [website](http://raeescoffee.ir/site/menu) , or see the below image

what's this border around the dropdown? how to remove it with CSS ?
in osx no border show but in google chrome, you can see that Stroke Borders...

[image]

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove border from `.dropdown.box_r.menu_box .shop_box` class.

```css
.dropdown.box_r.menu_box .shop_box {
    border: 0px;
}
```

Comment: thank you I don't know border is a default

Comment: You're most welcome :) @kiamoz

Answer (score 2):

Add below css to remove the border. `border: 0px;`

```
.dropdown.box_r.menu_box .shop_box {
    height: 60px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    color: #175832 !important;
    border: 0px;
}
```

Comment: thank you I don't know border is a default